# How to set gui specific options in neovim

Tags: neovim

I want to set `cursorcolumn` option in my `init.lua` only if GUI is running.

I've tried so:

```
vim.rpcnotify(1, 'Gui', {Option = {cursorcolumn=true}})
```

and with autocommand:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "UIEnter" }, {
  callback = function()
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufWinEnter" }, {
      callback = function()
        vim.opt.cursorcolumn = true
        end,
    })
  end,
})
```

but neither of them works as expected.
How should I do it properly?